# Plotting exact Solution (error)

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

This code is to get a plot of an exact function, where the function is the array of y defined in fn1. the error is "have shapes {} and {}".format(x.shape, y.shape))

ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (401,) and (2, 401)

```
def fn1( interval, N):
    x = numpy.linspace(interval[0], interval[1], N+1)
    y = numpy.array([numpy.exp(-1000*x),(1000/999)*(numpy.exp(-x)-numpy.exp(-1000*x))])
    return x, y


interval=numpy.array([0,0.1])
N=400

x,y=fn1(interval,N)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
plt.semilogy(x, y[:,0], 'b+')
```

Comment: You have as input interval, but you set interval `= 0.1`. Therefore `interval[0]` and `interval[1]` gives you errors because the interval is no list or array.

Answer (score 2):

You defined `interval`, but you did not use it as the argument into your function `fn1`, but instead used 0.1 as the argument.

Therefore you need to use this:

```
x, y=fn1(interval, 400)
```

Answer (score 0):

the error was that it should have been

```
plt.semilogy(x, y[0,:], 'b+')
```

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17956530)

Comment: @Alp - this does appear to be a solution to the problem, rather than additional information.  Therefore, a self-answer is the appropriate action.  It would benefit from some additional explanation, but it is still an answer.

Comment: @TobySpeight The original question was asking about a different error, when he first put `x,y=fn1(0.1, N)`. He edited the question when a new error occurred, and posted the answer to that.